# Updating one column based on parameter from another column in mssl1

Tags: sql-server

Please I want to update my `client` database based on the job type

```
id    Job_type  Meal_Ticket
---------------------------
 1       x        20
 2      2x        12
```

Meaning if I click on add 20 meal tickets on button click, it should update to this:

```
id  Job_type    Meal_Ticket
----------------------------
 1     x           40
 2    2x           52
```

I tried

```
UPDATE Staff
SET Rticket = CASE 
                 WHEN Jobtype = 'x' THEN Rticket = SUM(Rticket + 20)
                 WHEN Jobtype = '2x' THEN Rticket = SUM(Rticket + 2*20)  
                 ELSE Rticket
              END
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
UPDATE Staff
SET Rticket = CASE WHEN Jobtype = 'x' THEN Rticket + 20
                   WHEN Jobtype = '2x' THEN Rticket + 40 END
WHERE Jobtype IN ('x', '2x');
```

The only problem I see with your logic is that you are using `SUM` to add two quantities, when you should just be using the `+` operator.

Comment: I want a situation where by if i update  staff database with 20  meal it becomes 20 for x  jobtype and 40 for 2x  job type